# lost data in the coreData

Tags: swift, core-data, swift4

My app will show teacher shedule, in the first controller teacher need to choose the right pair (first, second, third) and then write nessesary data (like what the subject name, room, number of group) now in my code if i write data in first pair and save, it will show to me, but if i write data in second pair and choose save button, the previous data in first pair is lost, so i have a problem with losing data, this is code for controller where i choose pair:

```
class ChoosePair: UIViewController {  

enum choosePair: Int{
    case FirstPair = 21
    case SecondPair = 22
    case ThirdPair = 23
    case FourPair = 24

}
   @IBAction func PairButtons(_ sender: UIButton){
            guard let day = choosePair.init(rawValue: sender.tag) else { return }
            switch day {
            case .FirstPair:
                let FirstPair = self
                UserDefaults.standard.set(21, forKey: "pairId")
                performSegue(withIdentifier: "SheduleTeacher", sender: self)
                break
            case .SecondPair:
                let SecondPair = self
                UserDefaults.standard.set(22, forKey: "pairId")
                performSegue(withIdentifier: "SheduleTeacher", sender: SecondPair)
                break
            case .ThirdPair:
                let ThirdPair = self
                UserDefaults.standard.set(23, forKey: "pairId")
                performSegue(withIdentifier: "SheduleTeacher", sender: ThirdPair)
                break
            case .FourPair:
                let  FourPair = self
                UserDefaults.standard.set(24, forKey: "pairId")
                performSegue(withIdentifier: "SheduleTeacher", sender: FourPair)
                break
        }
}
}
```

And the code for second controller(where i write data and save it in CoreData)

```
class SheduleTeacher: UIViewController {

var pairId =  UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "pairId")

@IBOutlet weak var subjectLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var roomLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var emailLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var groupLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var captainLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var subjectField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var roomField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var timeField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var groupField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var captainField: UITextField!

let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Users")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    do {
        let result = try context.fetch(request)
        for data in result as! [NSManagedObject] {
            subjectField.text = data.value(forKey: "subject\(pairId)") as? String
            roomField.text = data.value(forKey: "room\(pairId)") as? String
            timeField.text = data.value(forKey: "time\(pairId)") as? String
            emailField.text = data.value(forKey: "emailGroup\(pairId)") as? String
            groupField.text = data.value(forKey: "group\(pairId)") as? String
            captainField.text = data.value(forKey: "captain\(pairId)") as? String
        }
    } catch {
        print("Failed")
    }
    subjectLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    roomLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    timeLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    emailLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    groupLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    captainLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
}

@IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Users", in: context)
let newUser = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
newUser.setValue(self.subjectField!.text, forKey: "subject\(pairId)")
newUser.setValue(self.roomField!.text, forKey: "room\(pairId)")
newUser.setValue(self.timeField!.text, forKey: "time\(pairId)")
newUser.setValue(self.emailField!.text, forKey: "emailGroup\(pairId)")
newUser.setValue(self.groupField!.text, forKey: "group\(pairId)")
newUser.setValue(self.captainField!.text, forKey: "captain\(pairId)")
do {
try context.save()
} catch {
print("Failed saving")
}
}    
}
```

And photo what I now have in CoreData

[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJmsE.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Predicates are used to limit the fetch to only get certain entities.

```
let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Users")
request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
```

Does not set a predicate so it always returns all the `Users` entities there are. The following has you iterate over every entity, that's why there is a for-loop.

```
for data in result as! [NSManagedObject] {
```

Here is an example how you can use a predicate to only get entities with `entity.pairId == pairId`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let context = AppDelegate.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Users")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "pairId = %@", argumentArray: [pairId])

    do {
        let results = try context.fetch(request)

        guard results.count == 1 else {
            fatalError("Bad count: \(results.count)")
        }

        guard let data = results.first! as? NSManagedObject else {
            fatalError("No NSManagedObject")
        }

        context.performAndWait {
            subjectField.text = data.value(forKey: "subject\(pairId)") as? String
            roomField.text = data.value(forKey: "room\(pairId)") as? String
            timeField.text = data.value(forKey: "time\(pairId)") as? String
            emailField.text = data.value(forKey: "emailGroup\(pairId)") as? String
            groupField.text = data.value(forKey: "group\(pairId)") as? String
            captainField.text = data.value(forKey: "captain\(pairId)") as? String
        }
    } catch {
        print("Failed")
    }

    // ...
}
```

The entity must of course have said attribute `pairId` for the predicate to work.

You would do something like this in the `save()` method too. There you could update the retrieved `Users` entity/create a new one if one does not exist.

One alternative is to delete the old one if one so exists and always create a new one on save.

The other alternative to "create a new one if one does not exist" is to pre-create for all four buttons and then fetch the entities on save and update them there. You would however have to check on startup too if they exist already else you would create on every startup four.

Answer (score 0):

In your `saveButton` func you create a new Users instance every time which mean data from pair two will not be written together with data for pair one but as a separate record. You need to update the existing object, the one you fetched in `viewDidLoad`, instead. (I very much doubt any data is lost)

That being said I think you need to rethink your design, having duplicate (or more) fields in the same entity looks like an awkward design that will be hard to maintain. A better solution would be to only have one group attribute, one subject attribute and so on and complement it with an attribute that holds the pairId.

Also, why is the entity name Users, it seems to hold no kind of user id?